# Problem with drag and drop and creating new element in html

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular7

im trying to implement a dinamic drag and drop (angular-material) in angular 7. The case is this:
I have multiples objects in a expansion panel with "Priority", i want to move that objects between the priorities/expansion panels (actually work). But, the problem start when i try to add a new empty "Priority", then when i try to drag and drop a object to the new priority, it dosnt work:

[this is the gif of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5LNi.gif)

**This is the html code:**

```
    <button (click)="createNewPrioridad()">Create new Priority</button>
    <br>
    <div cdkDropListGroup>
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let item of fleet" (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
                         (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
          Priority
        </mat-panel-title>
    
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <div class="example-list" *ngIf="item.children"
      cdkDropList
      [cdkDropListData]="item.children"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of item.children" cdkDrag>
          {{item.item}}
          <button (click)="checkIndex(item)">Checke Index</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
    </div>
```

**This is the ts code:**

```
  fleet: any[] = [
    {
      Item: 'Priority 1',
      children: [
        { item: 'Admiral Flankson', tipo: 'Mother' },
        { item: 'pvt. centeras',tipo: 'Son' },
        { item: 'pvt. leeft',tipo: 'Father' },
        { item: 'pvt. rijks',tipo: 'Son' },
      ],
    },
    {
      Item: 'Priority 2',
      children: [
        { item: 'Admiral Parkour', tipo: 'Mother' },
        { item: 'pvt. jumph', tipo: 'Brother' },
        { item: 'pvt. landts', tipo: 'Son' },
        { item: 'pvt. drobs', tipo: 'Son' },
      ],
    },
    {
      Item: 'Priority 3',
      children: [
        { item: 'Admiral Tombs', tipo: 'Father' },
        { item: 'pvt. zomboss', tipo: 'Son' },
        { item: 'pvt. digger', tipo: 'Son' },
        { item: 'pvt. skaari' , tipo: 'Son'},
      ],
    },
  ];



  panelOpenState:any
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<{}[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer == event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    }
    console.log(this.fleet);
  }

  
  checkIndex(item:any){
    console.log(item, 'aca esta el item para editar')
  }

  createNewPrioridad(){
    this.fleet.push({Item: "",children: ""})
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a new priority item, you are initializing the `children` property to an empty string.

```
createNewPrioridad(){
  this.fleet.push({Item: "",children: ""})
}
```

So the `div.example-list` with the `cdkDropList` is not rendering in that case because the `*ngIf` clause evaluates to `false`

```
<div class="example-list" *ngIf="item.children"
  cdkDropList
  [cdkDropListData]="item.children"
  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
>
```

Initialize `children` to an empty array `[]` instead and give the `div` a minimum height with css, and the problem should be solved.

cheers

Comment: Hi, ty for the answer, i initialize the children as an empty array , but still not working

Comment: have you also add a minimum height to the `.example-list` div?

Comment: sorry, i didnt add it! now its working!!! ty very muchhhhh!! its work perfect! you rock!